# Applescript or Automator service that automatically trusts certificates

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, keychain

I would like to know, if there is a way to make an Automator service or an Applescript that automatically trusts a root certificate. If possible without a prompt for password or Admin privileges. Could it be possible to do that maybe with `tell application "Keychain Access"`

or

```
do shell script "sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <certificate>"
```

If possible without the sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Undesirable Behaviour

There is no intended way to add trusted [root certificates](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/) without requiring authorisation from the user or an administrator.

Any method that manages to add a trusted root certificate without confirming, at some stage, the credentials of the user would be considered a serious security bug.

### What is the Risk?

Once a [root certificate is trusted](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ca_program.html), it provides an automatic degree of trust for other certificates, applications, and content.

If a script, process, or tool could add trusted root certificates without authorisation, then it opens the possibly to perform malicious actions on a Mac – without the user knowing.

Comment: Thanks. I would expose myself alot if I would try something like that.