# Automatic certificate creation?

Tags: terminal, xcode, keychain

To add 3rd party plugins in Xcode, one should [create their own certificate](https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim2/blob/master/SIGNING_Xcode.md) and to sign Xcode with it. But self-signed certificates expire after 1 year. How can I make specific code to be executed every year? Probably there's a way, but then I have another problem -- is there a way to create certificates with terminal, not through `Keychain Access` app?

Also is it [unsafe](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186619/applescript-or-automator-service-that-automatically-trusts-certificates)? I don't see any difference between manual certificate creation and automatic, so if it is unsafe, then creating such certificates is overall unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use command line tools to issue your own self-signed certificates. These need not be limited to one year.

There is no difference between Keychain Access created certificates and those you create using command line tools.

## openssl

With `openssl` you can create certificates of any duration. The question and answers for [how to create a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl) will get you started. The command is effectively:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 730
```

The command above will result in a two year self-signed certificate.

### Automatic versus Manual

Regarding safety, there is no difference in safety between certificates created by Keychain Access's graphical interface and those by command line tools.

The [safety of self-signed certificates can be an issue](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38727/is-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-much-better-than-nothing). Self-signed certificates are not signed by a trusted third party. This third party signature typically only matters when the certificate is being used outside of your immediate environment – which it is not for this situation.

### Ad-Hoc

You can also [ad-hoc codesign an application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288291/what-are-the-restrictions-of-ad-hoc-code-signing) without a certificate:

```
sudo codesign -f -s - /Applications/Xcode.app
```